# Match a pattern within a block of text bounded by two different patterns

Tags: bash, sed

Is there a way to match a pattern within a block of text whose boundaries are two unique patterns on different lines? By that I mean:

```
/*some comment*/
void something_patternWord1()
{
   some_code;
   some_code;
   some_code_patternWord3;
   some_code;
}
/*some comment patternWord2
```

**Desired Output:**

```
/*some comment*/
void something_patternWord1()
{
   some_code;
   some_code;
   new_line_of_some_code;   //after performing sed command
   some_code_patternWord3;
   some_code;
}
/*some comment patternWord2
```

**What I've tried:**

```
sed '/patternWord1/,/patternWord2/{/patternWord3/i new_line_of_some_code;}' inputFile > outputFile
```

The above command doesn't seem to be working.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to achieve is using `bash` script, read in some stuff from `.csv` file, and if the word read in is `someWord` then search for a block of text bounded by `patternWord1` and `patternWord2`,  match `patternWord3` within that block of text and insert some code above it.

I have many `.cpp` files with many different functions and therefore many combinations of different `patternWord1` and `patternWord2`.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with `sed`, and is `sed` the best tool for something like this?

Perhaps another approach: would it be possible for me to use `if-then` statements in `bash` while having the script read in a `.cpp` file, and *then* use the `sed` command to match for `patternWord3` and insert a new line of code?

If you could help me out with `sed` that would be great, but also I'm open to other suggestions as well if it make more sense/it is more efficient. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is to tell the insert command where to stop.

You may do it several ways, either placing the inserted string on a new line, or by closing the sed command with the `'` where the inserted line should end.

You may use

```
sed -e '/patternWord1/,/patternWord2/{/patternWord3/i\
   new_line_of_some_code;
}'
```

Or,

```
sed -e '/patternWord1/,/patternWord2/{/patternWord3/i \ \ \ new_line_of_some_code;' -e '}' inputFile > outputFile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kpL21j):

```
s='/*some comment*/
void something_patternWord1()
{
   some_code;
   some_code;
   some_code_patternWord3;
   some_code;
}
/*some comment patternWord2'

sed -e '/patternWord1/,/patternWord2/{/patternWord3/i \ \ \ new_line_of_some_code;' -e '}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
/*some comment*/
void something_patternWord1()
{
   some_code;
   some_code;
   new_line_of_some_code;
   some_code_patternWord3;
   some_code;
}
/*some comment patternWord2
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the swift response with a working solution! Could you explain the syntax behind it? It seems like my command was pretty close but obviously it's missing the rest which is why it didn't work.

Why does the command end at semi-colon, and start again with -e?

Comment: @TheVirtuoso The insert command should know where the inserted string ends, and it goes up to the `'`, the `}` ends up in the added string and it becomes "invisible" for the sed command, and the block becomes "corrupt".